# Optional unwrapping for class properties Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

Let's say I have the following class definition:

```
class Request {
    let url: NSURL?

    init?(url: String) {
        guard let self.url = NSURL(string: url) else {
            self.url = nil
            return nil
        }
     }
}
```

The guard statement doesn't work so I'm having to do the following:

```
let url: NSURL?

init?(url: String) {
    guard let _ = NSURL(string: url) else {
        self.url = nil
        return nil
    }
    self.url = NSURL(string: url)!
}
```

Which feels quite long - is there another, simpler way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve which is to create a failable initialiser whose only property takes a value from NSURL (which returns an optional). The initialiser is to fail and return nil if the NSURL value returns nil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first version could work, you just forgot to give guard a variable name for the unwrapped value (you used self.url instead, that's the mistake):

```
class Request {
    let url: NSURL?

    init?(url: String) {
        guard let value = NSURL(string: url) else {
            self.url = nil
            return nil
        }
        self.url = value
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Swift allow replacing variable names with `_` if you don't use them later?

Comment: Yes it does, but as you said it's only relevant if you don't need the value - here we need it.